# How to pass Linq grouping as parameter to custom extension method

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query where I am getting response values to a set of questions. I group the response data by question, and then perform various aggregations on the responsedata, such as averaging them. I also count the proportion of responses that could be classified as "high", "middle" and "low", based on specifying response option value ranges.

```
var result = ItemResponses
        .Where (ir => ir.ItemID < 4 && ir.AssessmentInstance.ProjectID == 5)
        .Select (ir => ir)
        .GroupBy (ir => new {
            ir.ItemID
        }).Select (grouped => new {
            ItemID = grouped.Key.ItemID,
            Average = (double)grouped.Average (g => g.OptionValue),
            ProportionHighScore = 
                (double)grouped.Where(g => g.OptionValue == 5 || g.OptionValue == 6).Count() 
                    / (double)grouped.Count(),
        });
```

I would like to move the code where I specify which optionvalues should be combined into a "high" response category away from the Linq query, and was considering to set up an extension method to do this. In the extension method I can then specify different combinations of response option values that I can score into a "high" score, across scenarious (for example, if the max response was not 6 but 10, then I would count options 8, 9, and 10 towards a "high" response category.

The extension method might look something like this:

```
public static double ProportionHighScore(this IGrouping<a,b> values, int ResponseOptionID)
{
    double ret = 0;
    switch (ResponseOptionID)
    {
        case 1:
            //code here to combine response options 5 and 6, and divide by total
            break;
        case 2:
            //code here to combine response options 8, 9 and 10 and divide by total
            break;
        case 3:
            //etc..
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But the question I have then is: how to I go about passing the Linq grouping values as a parameter into the extension method? The type of the IGrouping b is an anonymous type.

**Update:**
I like the idea of just doing `GroupBy (ir => it.ItemID)` so that I get access to `"IGrouping<int, ItemResponse>"`. But in the code here I simplified a bit. In my actual code there are a few more things going on, such as reversing the OptionValue scores if an item is flagged as "`IsReversed`".

```
var result2 = ItemResponses
        .Where (ir => ir.ItemID < 4 && ir.AssessmentInstance.ProjectID == 5)
        .Select (ir => new {
            ItemID = ir.ItemID,
            OptionValue =
              (
                  //Reverse option value of items that are flagged to require reverse scoring
                  ir.Item.IsReversed == 0 ? ir.OptionValue : 
                  ((ir.ResponseScaleOption.ResponseScale.MaxValue + 1) - ir.OptionValue)
              ),
            }) 
        .GroupBy (g => new {g.ItemID})
        .Select (grouped => new {
            ItemID = grouped.Key.ItemID,
            Average = (double)grouped.Average (g => g.OptionValue),
            ProportionHighScore = 
                (double)grouped.Where(g => g.OptionValue == 5 || g.OptionValue == 6).Count() 
                    / (double)grouped.Count(),
        });
```

In some versions of this query I also include fields from some joined tables as well. So the need to reverse the OptionValues is one reason why I assumed I needed an anonymous type. Perhaps I need to create a new class that I can project into ("`ItemResponseForAggregation`", or some such name), and then be able to do `IGrouping<int, ItemResponseForAggregation>` for my extension parameter?

Comment: No, it is the `a` of `IGrouping<a,b>` that is the anonymous type at that point of the code. Don't create a `new { ir.ItemID }` but simply `.GroupBy (ir => it.ItemID)`. In this way you'll have a `IGrouping<int, ItemResponse>`

Comment: Again with the anonymous types with only one property (`GroupBy (ir => new { ir.ItemID })`) Why do people do that? Why not simply `GroupBy (ir => ir.ItemID)` ?

Comment: Ah... and `.Select (ir => ir)` is totally useless.

Comment: LINQ to what? Entities, Objects etc. Note that if it's a LINQ to Entities, you can't use custom function inside the `select` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass anonymous types in this way. They have to be in the immediate execution context to treat them as if they were strong types. Create a lightweight type so you can pass this in, and then add a parameter constraint on parameter 'b' to enforce that it must be of the type you've created.

Comment: The anonymous class isn't even necessary here, so neither is a custom class.

Comment: I hear you @juharr, but I'm just giving an answer to the OP without further analysis of other ways of solving it.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I may need to consider using a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

I did a mock up in LINQPad of what I *think* you're looking for (if I am understanding the requirements correctly):

```
void Main()
{
    var ItemResponses = new List<ItemResponse>();

    var result = ItemResponses
        .Where(ir => ir.ItemID < 4 && ir.AssessmentInstance.ProjectID == 5)
        .GroupBy(ir => ir.ItemID)
        .Select(
            grouped => new {
                ItemID = grouped.Key,
                Average = (double)grouped.Average(g => g.OptionValue),
                ProportionHighScore = grouped.ProportionHighScore(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            }
        );

    result.Dump();
}

public class ItemResponse 
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int OptionValue { get; set; }
    public AssessmentInstanceItem AssessmentInstance { get; set; }
}

public class AssessmentInstanceItem
{
    public int ProjectID  { get; set; }
}

public static class ItemResponseExtensions
{
    public static double ProportionHighScore(this IGrouping<int, ItemResponse> values, params int[] ResponseOptionID)
    {
        double count = 0;
        double total = values.Count();

        foreach (int r in ResponseOptionID)
            count += (double)values.Where(g => g.OptionValue == r).Count();

        return count / total;
    }
}
```

In the extension method, the `params` parameter allows you to specify as many options as you need. Then I am just looping through the options, adding the count for each response option.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty close to what I'm after. As mentioned in the update, I need to do some adjustments to the OptionValues in ItemResponse (and also often add in some other fields), so I may need to add a lightweight type (as suggested elsewhere) and use that for my extension parameter.